# creating an iOSOpenDev application and a tweak in the same package

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, theos

I've spent three days looking how to create (using iOSOpenDev) one package (.deb) containing an application and a tweak at the same time and I could not find anything.

It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is in the xcode project, create two targets (one tweak and one application), both using iOS open dev, and then package them in the same deb. The way you would package them both is creating the correct path to the applications folder (/Applications/YourApp.app) and the path to where your tweak goes (/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraies) in the same deb folder, and then build the folder by typing this in terminal

```
sudo dpkg-deb -b YourDebFolder
```

The folder should look like this
[image]
Where `DEBIAN` contains the control file, `Library` contains a subfolder named `MobileSubstrate`, which then contains another subfolder `DynamicLibraries`, which contains the tweak, and the `Applications` folder contains the `YourApp.app` file.

Comment: Hi Chris, I did exactly this and the tweak works fine but the application opens and closes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the file you're putting in the `Applications` a .app bundle, and does it run correctly from Xcode?

Comment: Sorry, your method works perfect. It was a problem between iOS 5 and iOS 6 compatibility. Thanks for all the help.